# Vue.js - Use list to generate navbar and row of checkboxes that control the main content

Tags: vue.js

I am starting out in Vue, and wanted a little kick start if that was possible. Im going to create a page that has three main elements all coming from one list of data.

The list of data is all related to hotels, so it will have a id, country, region, name, image, address. And from that list I want a permanent navbar of all the countries in the list, and then when you click the country, on the left appears a vertical list of checkboxes that contain the regions, and in the main area the full list of hotels for that country.

But when you select the checkboxes the hotels update to filter to only show the hotels for those regions selected.

As a starting point I’m thinking something like this below, but its not right, the regions checkboxes dont appear when you click the buttons. After that ideally the hotels appear in the main section that relate to that region, I’m not at that part yet though.

```
<div id="hotelPage">
<div id="navBar">
<span v-for="country in showCountries" :key="country.country">
 <button v-on:click="showHotelsByCountry(country.country)">{{ country.country }}</button>       
</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="bodyWrapper">
  <div id="checkboxLeft">
  <ul>
   <li v-for="region in showRegionsByCountry()" :key="region.region">
       <label for="region.region">{{ region.region }}</label>
       <input 
        type="checkbox"
        id="region.region"
        v-model="regionCheckBoxes" 
        value="region.region">
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelsRight">
    <div v-for="hotel in hotels">123</div>
  </div>
 </div>    
 </div>

new Vue({
 el: '#hotelPage',
 data: {
  hotels: [
  {id: 0, hotelName: "hotel 1", country: "UK", region: "London", address: "road 1", image: "image1"}, 
 {id: 1, hotelName: "hotel 2", country: "USA", region: "New York", address: "road 2", image: "image2"}, 
 {id: 2, hotelName: "hotel 3", country: "France", region: "Paris", address: "road 3", image: "image3"},
 {id: 3, hotelName: "hotel 4", country: "UK", region: "Cardiff", address: "road 4", image: "image4"},
 {id: 4, hotelName: "hotel 5", country: "UK", region: "Cardiff", address: "road 5", image: "image5"},
 ],
  country: ""
 },
 methods: {        
  showRegionsByCountry: function(countryType) {
        if(countryType != "") {
           return this.hotels.find((item) => item.country == countryType);
        }
  }
  },
  computed: {
  showCountries: function() {
           return this.hotels.reduce((seed, hotel) => {
                    return Object.assign(seed, {
                    [hotel.country]: hotel
                });
              }, {});
         }
   }
});
```

Comment: Well, you're not approaching filtering correctly. You're thinking about your filtered objects as a different, mutated array. Think of it as a *"perspective"* or an *"angle"* on the source unmodified array.  That's why you need a getter, not a method. Your hotels should filter by country if a country is set or return all hotels. Therefore all you need to do when you click the button is to actually populate the "country" value, which is already used by the computed. Vue will update.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, and am building it here if that helps, but have had a go. The idea is that the countries show as they do in the navbar, then on click of a country the checkboxes appear on the left that relate to the country, but no duplicates, and then all the hotels appear for the country, but like you say when filtered by the checkboxes they only show the hotels for that country in that region.https://jsfiddle.net/accend4web/hj02kf6z/172/

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#hotelPage',
  data: {
    hotels: [
      {id: 0, hotelName: "hotel 1", country: "UK", region: "London", address: "road 1", image: "image1"},
      {id: 1, hotelName: "hotel 2", country: "USA", region: "New York", address: "road 2", image: "image2"},
      {id: 2, hotelName: "hotel 3", country: "France", region: "Paris", address: "road 3", image: "image3"},
      {id: 3, hotelName: "hotel 4", country: "UK", region: "Cardiff", address: "road 4", image: "image4"},
      {id: 4, hotelName: "hotel 5", country: "UK", region: "Cardiff", address: "road 5", image: "image5"},
      {id: 5, hotelName: "hotel 6", country: "USA", region: "Chicago", address: "road 6", image: "image6"},
      {id: 6, hotelName: "hotel 7", country: "USA", region: "Detroit", address: "road 7", image: "image7"},
    ],
    selectedCountry: "",
    selectedRegions: []
  },
  computed: {
    filteredHotels() {
      return this.hotels
        .filter(h => this.selectedCountry
          ? h.country === this.selectedCountry
          : true)
        .filter(h => this.selectedRegions.length
          ? this.selectedRegions.includes(h.region)
          : true)
    },
    countries() {
      return [...new Set(this.hotels.map(h => h.country))]
    },
    countryRegions() {
      return this.selectedCountry
        ? [...new Set(this.hotels
            .filter(h => h.country === this.selectedCountry)
            .map(h => h.region))]
        : []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setCountry(country) {
      this.selectedCountry = country === this.selectedCountry
        ? ''
        : country;
      this.selectedRegions = [];
    }
  },
});
```

```css
#bodyWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#bodyWrapper>* {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="hotelPage">
  <div id="navBar">
    <span v-for="country in countries" :key="country">
 <button v-on:click="setCountry(country)">{{ country }}</button>       
</span>
  </div>
  <div id="bodyWrapper">
    <div id="checkboxLeft">
      <h4>Country regions:</h4>
      <ul v-if="countryRegions.length">
        <li v-for="region in countryRegions" :key="region">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedRegions" :value="region">
            {{ region }}
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div v-else>Select a country</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Hotels:</h4>
      <div v-for="hotel in filteredHotels">{{hotel.hotelName}}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Data:</h4>
      <pre>selectedCounty: {{selectedCountry}}
contryRegions: {{countryRegions}}
selectedRegions: {{selectedRegions}}
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is more to show you how to implement methods/functionality and how to approach working with your data, than to actually do what you're trying to do. As you can see, I've changed all of your `computed`/`methods`, and that's the purpose of my answer.

Comment: oh thats awesome, thats much simpler than mine. Ye basically you click a country and the regions show as you have it, but what I need thats different is that you dont build up the hotels, instead you only filter them per country, so lets say you click UK, at first all the UK hotels will appear and then you can filter by the regions. But if you then click France, the same happens again, all the french hotels appear and you can filter by regions in France. If when you returned to UK the filters are still working that would be awesome. But im so grateful for the help.

Comment: in the input :value, would you add all the hotel components in there, as id need all the components to design the template for it, so like name at the top, then image, then address, that sort of thing.

Comment: Updated. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Im so reluctant to reply and say not quite, as its awesome, but the regions work the other way around. So when you click the country all the hotels appear, so in the UK there 3, and 2 regions. So with all the hotels there,lets say you only want to see the London ones, you click London and only the London ones appear, and then if no checkboxes are selected they all appear again. Does that make sense, so the checkboxes filter the hotels down not up.

Comment: I changed it, but the point here is that you take it and play with it. In other words, I won't change it everytime you want something different. I'm showing you how to use it so you can change it yourself. So you wanted to show all hotels in a country when no region is selected and to also reset `selectedRegions` when changing country. Done.

Comment: thank you very much for all your help, i pushed it on, and there was no other way to say thank you, got it this far - https://jsfiddle.net/accend4web/hj02kf6z/421/

Comment: @lee: I cleaned it up a bit, left a few comments, too: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/c1kexq47/
Happy coding & stay safe.